# Multiple Objects with same name in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I have been learning Objective-C from Big Nerd Ranch Book. I am stuck on 21st chapter example code.

Here is class BNREmployee header and Main file code.

**Header**

```
@interface BNREmployee : BNRPerson
{
    NSMutableArray *_assets;
}

@property (nonatomic) unsigned int employeeID;
@property (nonatomic) unsigned int officeAlarmCode;
@property (nonatomic) NSDate *hireDate;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *assets;
- (double)yearsOfEmployment;
- (void)addAsset:(BNRAsset *)a;
- (unsigned int)valueOfAssets;

@end
```

**Main.m**

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            // Create an instance of BNREmployee
            BNREmployee *mikey = [[BNREmployee alloc] init];

            // Give the instance variables interesting values
            mikey.weightInKilos = 90 + i;
            mikey.heightInMeters = 1.8 - i/10.0;
            mikey.employeeID = i;

            // Put the employee in the employees array
            [employees addObject:mikey];
        }
```

So, my question is how are we creating multiple objects for BNREmployee class with same name i.e., 'mikey'. It is done inside the loop. But, how does it work, why the compiler is allowing that? Thanks

Comment: Objects don't have names (unless they contain, eg, a `name` property).  Pointers have names.  Entirely different things (and a fundamental point you should understand BEFORE trying to code in Objectiver-C).

Comment: Objects and pointers equally don't have names. Variables have names.

Comment: @tenfour - Point taken!

Comment: There are no names in assembly, only addresses

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29#Block_scope

Answer (score 5):

This is a very basic syntax question about objective-C.
`mikey` is a variable that points to an instance of a `BNREmployee`. Each loop iteration, you create a new `BNREmployee` instance, and overwrite `mikey` to point to the new instance.

This line:

```
BNREmployee *mikey = [[BNREmployee alloc] init];
```

Creates an instance of `BNREmployee`, and assigns it to `mikey`.
You can create another instance of `BNREmployee` and do the same again:

```
mikey = [[BNREmployee alloc] init];// same thing again.
```

Doing this in a loop is basically the same as doing this. A simpler example is:

```
int mikey = 1;
mikey = 2;
mikey = 3;
```

This is the same concept; you're creating integers and assigning them to `mikey`.

In your code, the instance is stored in `employees` via the line `[employees addObject:mikey];`.
Now the `BNREmployee` instance you created is stored in multiple places: once in `mikey`, and once
somewhere in `employees`. When the loop continues, `mikey` gets reassigned to another new instance.
`employees` continues to accumulate the instances you created.

Why do you think the compiler shouldn't allow this?

Comment: In one line "You are **over*writing*** `mikey` every iteration".

Comment: Eloquence never was my strength :)